# Howto detect that a Lua script is running on CORE?

Tags: lua, operating-system, game-engine, lua-api, coregames

I would like to code

```
if (???) then
-- Code which is intended to run specially on CORE ( e.g. special references to CORE objects )
else
-- Code which is not intended to run on CORE ( e.g. the standard "require()",..)
end
```

How to do this?
I guessed that I might do it with "os" library functions, but I did not get a clue.

Sincerely
Rolf

Answer (score 2):

Some of Lua's standard functions have been removed in Core.

So if you for example have access to the io library you're not running your script from within Core.

```
if not io then
  print("not running standard Lua")
end
```

Alternatively find something that only exists in Core.

```
if CoreObject then
  print("we're likely running Core")
end
```